# Looking For Steps In Migrating Ruby 1.8.7 Web Application To Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.9.3

I am having an big old ruby on rails application

```
ruby version -  1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352)

rails version - 2.3.16
```

**currently there is no plan in migrating rails version**

As far as i know the performance of ruby 1.9.x is 2 times faster than 1.8.7

**Questions:**

1) I would like to know whether rails 2.3.16 is fully compatible with ruby 1.9.3-p385 ?

2) I am looking for basic generic steps in only migrating ruby 1.8.7 to ruby 1.9.3 without upgrading rails 2.3.x to rails 3.xx

3) And i would like to know the migration complexity level and issues?

**Note:**

I am looking for answers, suggestions, comments and reviews from those who really involved in ruby app migration from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 by sticking with rails 2.3.x

Answer (score 1):

I found this migration guide, maybe it'll give you answers. http://developer.uservoice.com/blog/2012/03/04/how-to-upgrade-a-rails-2-3-app-to-ruby-1-9-3/

From what I read, it can be quite a pain in the ass, since rails 2.3 does not support ruby 1.9.

If you can do it, I'd suggest migrating your rails anyway, at least 3.0 (before the asset pipeline) : it will still be a pain in the ass (as with any big migrations), but there are tools like rails_upgrade meant to facilitate this process.

Answer (score -2):

[Update](http://a-developer-life.blogspot.in/2012/01/migrate-rails-application-to-latest.html) a Rails application to the latest Ruby version with Rbenv.

Comment: As for my understanding, I think Rbenv is more or less equivalent to RVM, I hope it doesn't helps in ruby application migration ie. (Rbenv won't help in code change factor)